# purpose of using "case `default`" syntax with swift enums

Tags: swift, enums

What is the purpose of using:

```
case `default`
```

in the following code-snippet?

```
private enum AnimationType: String {
    case linear
    case easeIn
    case easeOut
    case easeInOut
    case `default`

    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .linear:
            return CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear.rawValue
        case .easeIn:
            return CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeIn.rawValue
        case .easeOut:
            return CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeOut.rawValue
        case .easeInOut:
            return CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut.rawValue
        case .`default`:
            return CAMediaTimingFunctionName.default.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `default` is a reserved keyword, so the backticks have to be added to use it.  I would recommend just using a different word.

Comment: Are you asking about the backtics or the name "default"?

Comment: ```default``` is keyword, but developer want use the keyword as enum's element. because although ```default``` is keyword, the element is clear representation as developer's purpose.